# Is there an Endpoint for liking a comment in Instagram Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I have seen tools out there that support Liking a Comment on Instagram via API.
I have not found anything in the documentation of Facebook on how to archieve this.

Is this possible and if yes how can i make a request to like a comment made to a page's post from a comment (I want to like as the page itself obviously)

I found this documentation, but it only shows how to reply and hide the comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/comment-moderation

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where you able to find a solution?